# How do I restrict the upload filesize in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a better way to do this ?

```
If FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 500000 Then
    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    Label1.Text = "Please enter a filesize less than 500kb!"
End If
```

Comment: [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094748/asp-net-check-file-size-before-upload)

Answer (score 0):

I think IIS 7 uses maxAllowedContentLength for specifying file upload size (KB). Edit your web.config like so:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```