# Regular expression for a file size

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a FileUpload control and want to limit the size of uploaded file.
What is the regular expression for a file size ?

I will use this in RegularExpressionValidator in Asp.Net.

Update :

I'm trying this to detect the file size without postback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what you want to do with a regex here ...

To limit the size of an uploaded file in the back-end you can use the `ContentLength` property. As per the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx) you can do this

```
int fileSize = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength;
// Allow only files less than 2,100,000 bytes (approximately 2 MB) to be uploaded.
if (fileSize > 2100000)
{
    // do something if the file is too big
}
```

If you want to do the validation on the client side (note that it should also be done on the server side) you can do what is described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639964/6838730). Here is an example code that should work

```
<input id="FileUpload1" type="file" name="file" />
<span id="errorMessage"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //this code will be executed when a new file is selected
    $('#FileUpload1').bind('change', function() {
        //converts the file size from bytes to Ko
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size / 1024;

        //checks whether the file is .png and less than 1Ko
        if (fileSize > 1) {
          $('#errorMessage').html("The file is too big")
              //successfully validated
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm searching for a regular expression - I mean regex code

Comment: Why ? A regex doesn't make sense here ... Regexes are meant to match patterns in text. The code above is adapted from the official documentation and is the official way to do this. Please describe how you intend to use a regex to verify the size of a file ...

Why isn't the code above satisfying you ?

Comment: Because I'm trying without doing a server postback.

Comment: Why couldn't it run ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157232/discussion-between-hqtunes-com-and-wndrr).

Comment: Okey I'm in chat

Comment: @HQtunes.com you shouldn't edit my post just to update the name of the var, it's not a big deal :-) Edits have to be reviewed every time

Comment: Sure, my last rename was for this: The file size limit was 1MB in code (for my name video) and I don't want people to laugh you.. Just not an important thing

Comment: @HQtunes.com Is it question solved ? can you accept it if yes

Comment: @GGO, my problem has fixed but my question is different. That's why I didn't accepted, thanks to ask.