# Upload very large file is tooo long

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET Core WebApi application and need to upload very large file. I have enabled JWT Auth/Authz

```
services.AddAuthentication(cfg =>
{
     cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, cfg =>
{ .. }
```

TTL of token is 2 minutes.

Then I have action in my controller like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(IFormFile file)
{
     if (file.Length.ToMegabytes() > 500)
     {
        throw new BadRequestException(nameof(file), "File size should not exceed 500 MB");
     }
}
```

and config in web host

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
 {
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
 })
```

When I  upload a large file (~1Gb) it is take a long time and then returns 401 before it step into my action.

How can I check that file has not valid size before it will be uploaded? Because uploading take a time more than 2 minutes and in a result I will get 401

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.Net Check file size before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094748/asp-net-check-file-size-before-upload)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, because I asked abiut asp.net core webapi but not for asp.net and jquery

Comment: afaik you can't do a proper check before file upload, because you'll need to upload the file in order for the server to know how big the file is.

Comment: but my token will be expire before all checks. how can I handle it without changes lifetime of token

Comment: I think main idea is not changed between any type of framework or lang, you should try to do that check first on client side

Comment: I do not have a client side, I have web api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when modelbinding a file upload, the entire file contents have to be spooled to the server *before* the action can be invoked. However, particularly if you're uploading large files, you should *not* be modelbinding the upload, but rather, streaming it. This should have the side effect of getting around your authorization problem, as well, because the action will be invoked immediately.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming) describe exactly how to stream large file uploads. It's not trivial, but this is how you should do it, regardless, for the best app performance and stability.

Comment: thanks, it make sense. can I use streaming but leave param `IFormFile file` in my action?

Comment: No. You have to manually parse the request body, as the documentation indicates. This is essentially what the modelbinder is doing, except in that case, it must finish streaming the file *before* it can bind the `IFormFile` param. This is because an action with a param cannot be invoked until the modelbinder has provided a value for that param.

Comment: So it means that I can't use Swagger anymore to upload file, right? is there any way to use swagger for streaming?

Comment: That's actually interesting. I hadn't considered the implications of this with something that actually *relies* on the method being self-documenting, like Swagger. *Theoretically*, if you add the attribute that disables modelbinding, I suppose you could keep the param; it just would have no value, so it would be a little confusing from a code perspective.

Comment: There *may* be a way to kind of trick out Swashbuckle/NSwag to tell it to offer an upload field without literally having a param. You'd have to check the respective documentation.